# Springcloud data flow 2.9.3 delete the TriggerProperties

Tags: stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

REcently upgraded my springcloud data flow version and I cant configure the trigger sources.

2.1.0 version
[image]

I cant configure it now... any help please ?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application properties were removed in favor of common spring integration properties. We will look into adding these to the property dialog. Meanwhile,  you should be able to manually type them into the stream definition or set as deployment properties. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/integration/IntegrationProperties.java#L325  e.g., `--spring.integration.poller.fixedDelay=2000`